# jquery does't work

Tags: jquery

I have been having this issue with my site where some of the scripts that I am putting into the site are not working and others are. The site is fully functional on one setup and fails on another even though it's the same code. I have 4 calls to different scripts in the header of my site. slider, custom animation, pagination, and some tools. I found the slider works fine but the next thing is broken. I can remove the slider and another section will start working. It's bizarre.

I have been doing some reading and decided to try and do it "The right way". I am calling all the scripts from the functions.php file using register script and then enqueue. I can see them all in the header when I view source and all the files are linked correctly. Knowing that WordPress includes jquery, I removed my jquery script that does allow things to work and just added this to the functions

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

i can see the script in the view source and that it is linked up correctly, but even will all other scripts removed accept the slider. The slider still don't work. So here is my simple little test that is suppose to have been done the right way,

```
 wp_equeue_script('jquery'); //this in in functions.php

 //in the header of my site, I am calling the slider
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').coinslider({
            width: 948,
            height: 367
        });

});
```

from my reading.. This should work but does not. Only if I include the jquery script which I am not suppose to half to do  does it start working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript included but alert() function not working](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/javascript-included-but-alert-function-not-working)

Comment: While I don't think it's an exact duplicate of that question I strongly believe the solution discussed there will work in your case. Also think about loading jQuery from a CDN (like Google) then you can make sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: There is a typo in `wp_equeue_script()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is obvious. The jQuery is loaded in [noConflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) mode. It means that the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available. You have to use closure, like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').coinslider({
            width: 948,
            height: 367
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In addition I would like to recommend you to create hook handler for `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. You need to enqueue `jquery` in this hook. In this case you will enqueue jquery only for frontend. Like following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse8170_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse8170_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think it would be more complete if you noted that hardcoding the jQuery into the header is a bad idea. It would be better to put it in a function hooked to wp_footer. If it is going to be hardcoded into the header, it has to go after wp_head().

Comment: @JPollock if you can edit my answer, feel free to extend it with your notes.

Comment: @JPollock A better edit would be to break the JS into a separate file and enqueue it with `in_footer` set to `true`. Don't ever hook script/style includes to `wp_footer`.

Comment: I wrapped all my scripts in teh function call above and used the built in jquery rather than calling the separate script. Hopefully this will be better. Everything seems to be working now. Thanks to all the comments. There was some good discussion here

Comment: @EAMann The reason I stopped doing it that way was that means I need to created a separate js file for initializing and a separate HTTP get to load it. Do that a few times and you're impacting page load times adversely. Also if you need to reinitialize via a callback, say after an AJAX page load, you've got code in two places, which is a copypasta disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Basically WordPress already loads jQuery by default, you don't have to enqueue jQuery from your functions.php. Because it runs in noConflict() mode you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

**Edit:**

Like mentioned by the other users jQuery **does not** load by default on frontend, so it should be enqueued...why the hell I never had to do this ;) . Does setting the `$deps` parameter to `array('jquery')` when using a script which needs jQuery within `wp_register_script` automically load jQuery without enqueue jQuery separately?

Comment: Actually this is incorrect. While WordPress does load jQuery on the admin site by default it is up to the theme/plugin author to load it. However, because most themes/plugins use jQuery it's often the case that one of the installed plugins/theme is calling it for us.

Comment: You guessed right @rftq : the $deps parameter for `wp_enqueue_script` is used to declare the script dependencies and load them before. Try for example to put `jquery-ui-tooltip` in the deps array to see how many cascaded dependencies are loaded (`jquery-ui-widget`, `jquery-ui-position`, `jquery-ui-core` and `jquery`) !